# Programmatically detect when outgoing call starts ringback tone (ringing to the other person)

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to know how to detect in android when an outgoing call is acceptable (but not yet accepted) by the other person and you receive the ringback tone.

I tried `PhoneStateListener` using method `onCallStateChanged(int state, String callingNumber)`, but the state only returns to me `2` (starts) and `0` (ends) and not when the call is acceptable by the other person (There is a time between you starts the call and the other phone receive the call and starts to ring)

There already are an android method to know it or what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your question my answer is **No**

**There is NO way** (sadly, because I need it) to detect the time of an outgoing call starts ringing.

It's impossible to detect by regular non-system application - no Android API. I could not find a way, I was googling the solution within very long time :-(